# Avoiding multiple toggles simultaneous

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I need some help with jquery toggle :D . So , I have 2 left bars (one for login , one for register ) but they can be toggled on simultaneos and that is not good ( 1- don't make sense 2- don't look good ) . I was searching for a solution but can't find one , probably didn't search with the good words . Can someone give me a solution ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.meniu-ico').click(function(){
        $('#sub-meniu-contulmeu').toggle( "slide" , 500);
    }); // sfarsit click user manage
    $('.inregistrare-ico').click(function(){
        $('#forma-inregistrare').toggle( "slide" , 500);
    }); // sfarsit click register
    $('.autentificare-ico').click(function(){
        $('#forma-autentificare').toggle( "slide" , 500);
    }); // sfarsit click login
}); // sfarsit jquery



<nav id='contulmeu'>
  <ul>
    <li><span class='meniu-ico'><a>Contul meu</a></span></li>
    <li><span class='inregistrare-ico'><a>Inregistrare</a></span></li>
    <li><span class='autentificare-ico'><a>Autentificare</a></span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please post some code here, easier to correct than to make new

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('a.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```